# C++ compiling error due to a conflict between the movement constructor and other non-movement one when using std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I am doing some "experiments" with move semantics in order to fully understand it. I have reached a point that I don't understand completely. This is because it seems that there is a conflict with a constructor like `A::A(B b)` and `A::A(B &&b)` when using `std::move`. Below is the code that explains this:

```
struct Item {
    Item() { }

    Item(const Item &other) {
        std::cout << "Item::Item(const Item& )\n";
    }
};

struct Container {
    Container(Item i) {
        std::cout << "Container::Container(Item )\n";
    }

    Container(Item &&i) {
        std::cout << "Container::Container(Item&& )\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Item i;
    Container c(std::move(i));
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile the above code, the followign error is shown:

```
error C2668: 'Container::Container' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\users\xe74139\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\project1\maincpp.cpp(21): could be 'Container::Container(Item &&)'
1>          c:\users\xe74139\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\project1\maincpp.cpp(17): or       'Container::Container(Item)'
```

I know that the constructor `Container(Item i)` makes no sense at all, but I still don't understand why C++ compiler sees a conflict between both `Container` constructors.

Why it can't determine that `Container c(i)` is for calling `Container(Item)` and `Container c(std::move(i))` is for calling `Container(Item &&)`?

**EDIT:** Or, in other words, why the constructor `Container(Item)` is valid for a call like `Container c(std::move(i))`?

Comment: Why would it? Both constructors are equally valid.

Comment: `Container(Item i)` is also ambiguous with `Container(Item& i)` if you pass without the `move`.  This isn't about move semantics.  This is about overloading by-value with by-reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the constructor Container(Item) is valid for a call like Container c(std::move(i))?

Because you can construct an `Item` when given the result of `std::move(i)` (which is an `Item&&`).

And like HowardHinnant said in a comment - it's the same for `Item` vs `Item&` - you can construct one when passed the other, so if you have both of these constructors defined you've created amibguity.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it's because the argument first evaluated, then passed. Once it's passed, it's just any `r-value`, and both your constructors would work. I'm not sure it's possible to have such an overload, and it doesn't make sense from my point of view.

Why not? Well, you are trying to define a container that forces movement of an element. From a design view, you have to consider that someone using that code may not want the data "stolen" (moved). I think it would make more sense in this context to have:

```
struct Item {
    Item() { }

    Item(const Item &other) {
        std::cout << "Item::Item(const Item& )\n";
    }
    Item(Item &&other) {
        std::cout << "Item::Item(Item&&)\n";
    }
};
```

This overload makes more sense - you will explicitly state when you want the object moved, and when copied (there's a default `move` here, but this way makes it more obvious). Now you just need

```
Container(Item i);
```

(without the other constructor) and calling it with

```
Container c(std::move(i));
```

is what we expect - instead of copying `i`, you're explicitly stating you want it moved, and `i` is in charge of handling this.

Comment: Yes of course, I understand that the constructor `Container(Item )` does not make sense at all, it was just for making some experiments.

Comment: Is there any difference here between using `Item(const Item &other)` and `Item(Item &other)` for copy?

Comment: @super yup - yes, one you can change, and one you can't (so is safer if you don't plan on making changing to the reference).